# Drag more than one jQuery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Can I drag and save to cookies more than one without repeating all the code?

```
$(function() {
     $('.demo').draggable({
        cursor: "move"
        ,

        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $.cookie('demox', $(this).css('left'));
            $.cookie('demoy', $(this).css('top'));
        }
    })
     .resizable({
                    aspectRatio: true,
            })
})

$(function() {

    if ($.cookie('demox') != null) {
        $('.demo').css('left', $.cookie('demox'));
    } 

    if ($.cookie('demoy') != null) {
        $('.demo').css('top', $.cookie('demoy'));
    } 
})
```

Comment: I tried to clean up the question, but it is still unclear to me what you are asking exactly.

Comment: lets say i want to drag more than .demo and i want to drag them seperataly   if i type $(".demo, .example") it will drag both of them and save them in the same place.i want to be able to drag more than one element and save them in cookies without typing over and over the same code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Is using a specific ID for each element an option to you? With this, you could attach the same handler to these objects and check it when the handler is called, by checking  `this`

By Handler I mean a

```
function handler(event, ui)
{
    $.cookie('demox_'+this.id, $(this).css('left'));
    $.cookie('demoy_'+this.id, $(this).css('top'));
}
```

And you can attach it do the draggable by just writing

```
$('.demo').draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    stop: handler
})
```

Of course you would have to give your ".demo"-Elements an ID.

I hope this something reasonable for you :)

P.S.: Later you can use the following:

```
$(function() {

    $('[id*="demoID_"]').forEach(function(element)
    {
        if ($.cookie('demox_'+element.id) != null) {
            element.css('left', $.cookie('demox_'+element.id));
        }

        if ($.cookie('demoy_'+element.id) != null) {
            element.css('top', $.cookie('demoy_'+element.id));
        } 
    });
});
```

I hope I don't have a typo in there :)

In this case your elements should have an ID like this: demoID_n and the cookies will be then stored in demox_demoID_0, demox_demoID_1 and so on